# Problem when using Guava as Maven dependency in Tycho build

Tags: java, maven, build, guava, tycho

I'm updating a tycho build to get all its dependencies off an eclipse target platform instead of dependencies written into poms. For that I have followed the instructions [here](https://xn--lubisoft-0za.gmbh/en/articles/using-maven-artifacts-in-pde-rcp-and-tycho-builds/) to set up the target platform.
I've also updated the build to use the target platform to locate the dependencies, and when running the build the logs suggest, that it is indeed working.

I'm having a problem with guava as a dependency though. When the build tries to resolve `guava 28.2-jre` it checks its transitive dependencies and then halts with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to resolve target definition C:\somepath\thetargetfile.target: Artifact 
MavenArtifactFacade [wrappedArtifact=jdk:srczip:jar:999:system] of location GroupId = 
com.google.guava, ArtifactId = guava, Version = 28.2-jre, ArtifactType = jar, 
IncludeDependencyScope = compile, MissingManifestStrategy = GENERATE, IncludeSource = true
is not a valid jar file
```

As far as I understand guava requires a jar with the currently used JDKs sources to work. From what I can see from the guava pom, this dependency is only required guava is built with a certain profile, which I don't need. Tycho seems to parse it as a required dependency though.
Since this build is meant to be as portable as possible I would like to avoid having to manually create this artifact and installing it locally on each device that should be able to run the build. Is there any way to make this work seamlessly within the build?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Eclipse Orbit](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.orbit) has pre-built Guava 27.1 and 30.1 plug-ins

Comment: @greg-449 The problem originally arose from wanting to use `mapdb 3.0.8` which requires `guava [28.2,29.0)`, therefore those 2 versions are not an option. I'm currently trying to work around the error by using an older and modified version of mapdb.